# Steam OpenID Authentication on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, openid

On the last weeks, I'm trying to implement a OpenID authentication on my laravel's website, but without success. I can't use [laravel/socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) because the package doesn't support steam and think not support OpenID auths too.

Then, I found the community driven [project](https://socialiteproviders.github.io/) for custom socialite adapters. But the adapters are a mess and uses obsolete dependencies.

A answer will help a lot of people. Help us :c

Comment: Check out this: https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth > This package is a Laravel 5 service provider which provides support
> for Steam OpenID and is very easy to integrate with any project that
> requires Steam authentication. It should do what you want. The `ReadMe` has detailed instructions on how to set it up.

Comment: I have been using the steam socialite for a while, never had problems

Comment: What's wrong with using the [Steam Socialite](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/steam/) package? What dependency issues do you have with it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Laravel Steam Auth](https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth)

Very easy setup:

1. Composer install

   `"invisnik/laravel-steam-auth": "2.*"`
2. Add the service provider to app/config/app.php, within the providers array.

   `'providers' => [
       Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamServiceProvider::class,
   ]`
3. Publish config: `php artisan vendor:publish`
4. Setup your route and API key in `config/steam-auth.php`
5. Add route: `Route::get('dologin', 'Auth\SteamController@dologin');`
6. Use this live code example, as code from readme not worked for me:

   ```
       <?php

       public function dologin(Request $request)
       {
           if ($this->steam->validate()) { 
               $info = $this->steam->getUserInfo();

               if (! is_null($info)) {
                   $user = User::where('token', $info->get('steamID64'))->first();
                   if (! is_null($user)) {
                       //Update user data, as it change over time..
                       $user->nick = $info->get('personaname');
                       $user->name = $info->get('realname') ?: '';
                       $user->avatar = $info->get('avatarfull');
                       $user->update();
                   } else {
                       $user = User::create([
                           'nick' => $info->get('personaname'),
                           'name' => $info->get('realname') ?: '',
                           'avatar' => $info->get('avatarfull'),
                           'token'  => $info->get('steamID64'),
                       ]);                    
                   }
                   Auth::login($user, true);
                   return redirect('/'); // redirect to site
               }
           } 
           return $this->steam->redirect(); // redirect to Steam login page
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Socialite Steam Login**

1. Composer Install

   ```
   // This assumes that you have composer installed globally
   composer require socialiteproviders/steam
   ```
2. SERVICE PROVIDER

   - Remove Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider from your providers[] array in config\app.php if you have added it already.
   - Add \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class to your providers[] array in config\app.php.

     ```
     'providers' => [
       // a whole bunch of providers
       // remove 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider',
       \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class, // add
      ];
     ```
3. Add the event and listeners

   ```
   protected $listen = [
     \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
     // add your listeners (aka providers) here
     'SocialiteProviders\Steam\SteamExtendSocialite@handle',
     ],
   ];
   ```
4. ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES in ,env file

   ```
   // other values above
   STEAM_KEY=yourapikeyfortheservice
   STEAM_REDIRECT_URI=https://example.com/login
   ```

sources:- http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/steam/

Hopefully, this helps with your steam login.